# distance between points in the Cartesian plane.

Tags: analytic-geometry

[image]Calculate the $\frac{AC}{CB}$ ratio, given the points:

$A(1,4);$

$B(1/2,3);$

$C(-2,-2).$

I did the calculations on the Cartesian plane and the result was $\frac{6}{5}$.Do you agree with this result?

Comment: I got a different result.  Please show your intermediate work

Comment: side point:  unlike your drawing, the line containing A, B, and C does not actually pass through the origin

Comment: now that you edited the question, I agree with your result (see below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result would be correct for $C(-2,\color{red}-2)$.

Comment: I posted an answer before you showed your work, but now I can tell from your work that you were using $C(-2,-2)$, instead of $C(-2,2)$ as your question stated

Comment: I already edited everything, your gave 6/5, now?

Comment: now that you changed $C(-2,2)$ to $C(-2,-2)$ in the question, I agree the answer is $6/5$

Comment: thank you! Jw